# Вопрос теоретический про объектный тип Object

Tags: c#

Понятно, что есть тип Object. И этот тип включает в себя такие методы.

```
public extern Type GetType();
public virtual bool Equals (object obj);
public static bool Equals (object objA, object objB);
public static bool ReferenceEquals (object objA, object objB);
public virtual int GetHashCode();
public virtual string ToString();
protected override void Finalize();
protected extern object MemberwiseClone();
```

Хотелось бы понять разницу и область применения.

```
     public virtual bool Equals (object obj);
        public static bool Equals (object objA, object objB);
  public static bool ReferenceEquals (object objA, object objB);
```

Вроде понятно, но какая то все равно каша в голове, подскажите на пальцах как это понять.

Comment: отчего бы просто [исходники](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab) не глянуть?

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо посмотрел, получается public static bool Equals это  тоже самое что == между двумя объектами, так ли я понял? А  это   static bool ReferenceEquals проверяет равные(друг другу) ли ссылки на объекты А и Б?

Comment: не совсем, это сначала каст их к `object`, а потом уже `==`

Comment: Да это как раз я понимаю, все приводим к Object, и затем эти объекты сравниваем. Как между собой, так и ссылки на эти объекты.